# Persistant augmentation with Area Target in Vuforia?

Tags: navigation, anchor, target, vuforia, area

Love vuforia but having a nightmare probleme:

- when using the Area target anchor, the space anchor works well but its not persistant. Meaning that if I move away from the anchor, the virtual world and objects disappear...
  Any idea on how to make it persistant ? So when the augmented content appears it doesnt go away and stay put ?

this is a nightmare and help would be MUCH MUCH appreciated !

thanks a lot

I use area target, the space anchoring works well, but I would like to keep track of the digital objects and positions even when I move away from the anchor.

Comment: Have you tried testing the AreaTarget with the Vuforia Creator App (https://library.vuforia.com/tools/creator-app)  or with the Unity sample? Can you reproduce the problem there?

Comment: I use the Unity sample. 
I will try, but isn’t it the same ? 
The problem is not related with detection but when I move away from the anchor, the 3D objects disappear :(

Comment: If id does not work on the vanilla Unity sample may I ask on which platform/device (e.g., iOS/iPad) are you testing?