# Keeping GameObj/VFX visible/position after Area Target lost

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, vuforia

here's my first post.

I've been learning Unity and C# for a month now, I couldn't find any comprehensible references for my level of understanding so I'm posting here.

---

I'm making an AR app prototype for IOS using unity3d + vuforia.

When deployed to my phone it displays the parented GameObjects, but as soon as the area target is lost everything disappears. My assumption is that I have to maintain the object location by specifying when the target is lost. I also tried different approaches but they did not work.

[Game Object / VFX parented to the Vuforia Area Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CITE.png)

[Using Extended Tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GFju.png)

[Play mode example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARpUE.jpg)

This is the code I tried to implement but it seems that either my IDE is not recognizing vuforia library or I am using outdated code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class AreaTargetObjectPersistence : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour areaTarget;
    private bool isTracking;
    private Vector3 initialPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        // Get the TrackableBehaviour component from the Area Target
        areaTarget = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (areaTarget)
        {
            // Register this script as the event handler for the Area Target
            areaTarget.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }

        // Store the initial position of the object
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // If the Area Target is currently being tracked
        if (isTracking)
        {
            // Update the object's position to match the Area Target's position
            transform.position = areaTarget.transform.position;
            transform.rotation = areaTarget.transform.rotation;
        }
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
        {
            // Area Target is being tracked
            isTracking = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Area Target is lost
            isTracking = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnTargetLost()
    {
        // Reset the object's position to the initial position when target is lost
        transform.position = initialPosition;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }
}
```

I get these errors:

1. CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TrackableBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2. error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ITrackableEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and also sometime it seem like It does not recognize OnTargetLost() and OntargetFound()

On Xcode various warnings about stuff being Deprecated

[I also tried looking into the known issue for iPhone but it doesn't seem like it](https://library.vuforia.com/release-notes/vuforia-engine-release-notes#:%7E:text=on%20the%20Camera.-,known%20issues,-All)

Should I use Anchors ?

[A similar Issue from another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75484368/persistant-augmentation-with-area-target-in-vuforia)

Thanks in advance for the help, Constructive Criticism and Advices are well accepted.

[github repository](https://github.com/Hue-Git-Rection/unity_ar_app_project)